# keep track of questions asked by others

Tags: feature-request

We are warned with e-mails or through the app when new answer to OUR questions are added, but sometimes I am interested also in other questions asked by other users, so I wondered: is it possible to keep track of a question asked by someone else?

I mean something like a feed rss.

Comment: it would be nice to get notified in the inbox ...

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't think you can use it for email notices you can track questions using the **Favorites** feature.  To mark any question, including your own, as a Favorite click the gray star below the vote arrows to turn it golden:

[image]

The question will then appear in the **Favorites** tab in of your profile page, and questions with new answers will be highlighted.  For more information see the main Meta Q&A:

- [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)